# Retrieve data from mysql php android

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns in my table present on phpmyadmin i want to retrieve those two column's last value into a string 
can anyone help me with the code
here is my php
I don't know how to retrieve it

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student");
if($query){

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{

$flag[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($flag));

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Include the names of the columns in your query and then choose something which can be identified as being "last" like a row id or date.

Comment: What are those two columns types? any of them `timestamp` or `auto-increment` or anything that you can sort the data by it and find the last record?